# In magit, I want to (easily) see how a piece of code changes over time with commits

Tags: magit

I'm curious if there's an easy way in Magit to see how a piece of code changes over time, i.e., with each commit.

I'd like to have one window open in Emacs, focusing on the code/function I want to see changes to, and another window (e.g., Magit log buffer or something) where, when I move up/down in the history of the file in the other window, I can see it evolve over time.

I've thought about this for a long time, but I've never been able to find it in the manual or even know what kind of keywords to look for. I hope I managed to explain it this time and someone out there understands what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `vc` or with magit:

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> runs the command
  `vc-region-history`.
- Using Magit, the equivalent command `magit-log-buffer-file`
  (<kbd>l</kbd> in the `magit-file-dispatch` menu; hence commonly it
  would be <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>M-g</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>).

With either of these commands you firstly mark a *region* you are
interested in, and they then give you (in a single buffer) a history
of that region: the sequence of commits which affected the region, and
the diff for each of those changes.

As such, a useful prefix is often <kbd>C-M-h</kbd> which runs the
command `mark-defun`.

Comment: Amazing, thank you SO MUCH! <3

Answer (score 0):

It’s not exactly what you describe, but there is `magit-blame-addition`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice function, but like you say. Not what I was looking for.